# "TypeError .. is undefined" in for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working with `BootstrapVue`.

**What I'm trying to do:** I have a `b-form-input` where I write in a **number** in it. After clicking on my `b-button` I want to add this to my `inputs`. This works well but now I want to check first if my **number** is still in my `inputs`.

**PROBLEM:** After trying to add something to my `inputs` I always get following error: `[Vue warn]: Error on v-on handler: "TypeError: this.inputs[i] is undefined"`

I've declared everything correct in my data and without the `for-loop` it's working well. What is the error in here? I could not figure it out..

also when I try to do this: `this.inputs[0].number` i get the correct data..

Thanks for trying helping me out!

*Code in my template:*

```
<b-form-input v-model="number"></b-form-input>
<b-button @click="addSomething(number)"></b-button>
```

*Code in my script:*

```
addSomething(number) {
  if(this.inputs != []) {
    for(let i = 0; i <= this.inputs.length; i++) {
      if(number === this.inputs[i].number) {
        console.log("Still existing!");
      } else if(number !== this.inputs[i].number) {
        this.inputs.push({
          INPUT_NUMBER: number,
        })
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the condition `i <= this.inputs.length` you are running over your array's bounds. In JavaScript overindexing an array returns `undefined`.

The fixed handler should be:

```
addSomething(number) {
  if(this.inputs != []) {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.inputs.length; i++) {
      if(number === this.inputs[i].number) {
        console.log("Still existing!");
      } else if(number !== this.inputs[i].number) {
        this.inputs.push({
          INPUT_NUMBER: number,
        })
      }
    }
  }
},
```